# On a proof regarding the sigma algebra generated by a single random variable.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

[image]

I left (b) and (c) for the sake of the curious.

What I am trying to do is Exercise (a) except that I recall that $\sigma(Y):= ( \{ w : Y(w) \in B \} : B \in \mathcal{B} )$ is the definition of sigma algebra of a random variable so I do not see what is there to prove in the first request.

Comment: Maybe you need to show that $\sigma(Y)$ is indeed generated by the $\pi$-system described? Once you have done that, you could do many probability calculations using the _cumulative probability distribution function (CDF) $F_Y(x) = P\{Y \leq x\}, x \in \mathbb R$ since you know that the set $\{Y \leq x\}$ is an event in the sigma-algebra $\sigma(Y)$, and hence we can talk of the probability that $\{Y \leq x\}$ occurs.

Comment: Simply *read the definition* 5 pages earlier, at the beginning of section 3.8...

Comment: @Did Which textbook is this exercise from?

Comment: @jesterII Why not ask the OP? David Williams, *Probability with martingales*.

Comment: @Did, for some reason the `@` handle cannot be used to notify the OP (who is notified automatically, apparently). Thanks.

Comment: @jesterII Yeah, so just post your query as a comment without the `@` thing and the OP will be notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look further to the front of the book, maybe you can find the definition of the generated sigma-algebra that the author uses.

Typically, the generated sigma-algebra is defined just in the way you described. In this case you only need to prove the second assertion of this exercise.

However, there are also other definitions. One possible definition is that $\sigma(Y)$ is the intersection of all sigma-algebras with respect to which $Y$ is measurable. If the author defines $\sigma(Y)$ in this way, you need to prove that it coincides with $Y^{-1}(\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: Indeed, 5 pages earlier, at the beginning of section 3.8...